ld: library 'ssl' not found on rust
I try to build in rust with diesel. 
When run cargo run An error occurs
  error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
    |
    = note: env -u IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET -u TVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET -u             XROS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET LC_ALL="C"
  ......
  = note: ld: library 'ssl' not found
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I think ssl is just protocol. 
So I can't install ssl. like brew install ssl 
How to install ssl? or How to resolve this problem?
My computer environment is...

Darwin 23.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.5.0: Wed May  1 20:16:51 PDT
2024; root:xnu-10063.121.3~5/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 arm64

My Cargo.toml is ...
[package]
name = "***"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "2.2.1", features = ["mysql", "chrono"] }
dotenvy = "0.15.7"
chrono = {version = "0.4.38", features = ["serde"]}
actix-web = "4.8"
actix-cors = "0.7"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }

[profile.release]
opt-level = 3

And cargo version is ... cargo 1.79.0 (ffa9cf99a 2024-06-03)
This is All logs
jun@MacBook-Air rust % brew install openssl
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
############################################################################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
############################################################################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
Warning: openssl@3 3.3.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 3.3.1, run:
  brew reinstall openssl@3
jun@MacBook-Air rust % cargo run           
   Compiling rust v0.1.0 (/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: env -u IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET -u TVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET -u XROS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET LC_ALL="C" PATH="/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/bin:/Users/jun/.cargo/bin:/Users/jun/.nvm/versions/node/v19.7.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/jun/.cargo/bin:/Users/jun/.nvm/versions/node/v19.7.0/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin" VSLANG="1033" ZERO_AR_DATE="1" "cc" "-arch" "arm64" "/var/folders/gt/2jj885xx1n7g6jq9ml1gq3v80000gn/T/rustcoR0MW0/symbols.o" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/our_story_rust-0cda4beb343ae7f3.104nr92xdqqgp85b.rcgu.o" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/our_story_rust-0cda4beb343ae7f3.1197h7ho19h3tiur.rcgu.o" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/our_story_rust-0cda4beb343ae7f3.11ie1aefiwffm94q.rcgu.o" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/our_story_rust-0cda4beb343ae7f3.12t9perj112y3fjt.rcgu.o" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/our_story_rust-0cda4beb343ae7f3.13utoz2rgcyylal4.rcgu.o" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/our_story_rust-0cda4beb343ae7f3.14wesdnddkh2lc6p.rcgu.o" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/our_story_rust-0cda4beb343ae7f3.170kkxszrcc8dnwg.rcgu.o" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/our_story_rust-0cda4beb343ae7f3.1737fn0r3eh6s7ak.rcgu.o" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/our_story_rust-0cda4beb343ae7f3.17x3sud5nrs0psmo.rcgu.o" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/our_story_rust-0cda4beb343ae7f3.251y2jgbf6n33it.rcgu.o" "-L" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/build/zstd-sys-9d57269d9a809450/out" "-L" "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/lib" "-L" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_cors-4c3933e1e73abde7.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_web-07079197f6761201.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libserde_urlencoded-8a233b06c49c03e5.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libserde_json-fe7f533d735faea5.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libryu-f3220b7d4b02bcbe.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_server-b136b318348105f3.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_router-fa7d152788ebab62.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libregex-374a67300cd12439.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libregex_automata-dc6e55656709ae70.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libaho_corasick-4d71a077666941ff.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libregex_syntax-4a74e0236c3137c3.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libcookie-c207a72a3afdfdce.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libtime-40e25195f3f38775.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libtime_core-fc344af787764b53.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libnum_conv-c1464ddbb622fa57.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libderanged-0da1ba2eda2a27ba.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libpowerfmt-22e066a305636db7.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_http-e58235c7b907592c.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/librand-61d1219d3fe7e1ea.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/librand_chacha-9fb50b76907cdbc6.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libppv_lite86-e03b84495378069e.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/librand_core-6641cddb1c921f98.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libhttparse-6d826a88712f6741.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libbrotli-5f3480bac2f3d76b.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libbrotli_decompressor-5d834d721b33b49c.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/liballoc_stdlib-9d9cda789372b8fa.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/liballoc_no_stdlib-0026e1892f1372b8.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libhttpdate-0dfa0cdeac218569.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libsha1-aaf472dd4ddbdb9c.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libdigest-d42dfb28f743913d.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libblock_buffer-4a21acbd00e8fe77.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libcrypto_common-0c0150409c6ffac6.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libgeneric_array-853a11acbc4bdacf.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libtypenum-a060b0c40df13c05.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libbase64-4cc6577c8d95857e.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/liblocal_channel-de1d63e4917c8a2c.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libbytestring-fc2eff83e2e903d9.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libencoding_rs-da46489f5b44f0d2.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/liblanguage_tags-81ef902cde820fc2.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libahash-736fe62a8448ea6b.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libgetrandom-791c7a954ef4fe46.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libzerocopy-45e3c269909d87f5.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libmime-e3214e3c5ce88e94.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libh2-06bb856b2a49c903.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libindexmap-cfb0cc5828c00d79.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libequivalent-739966a41e941e2b.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libhashbrown-4830bc457cc773cd.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libfutures_util-17905b552adcc69d.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libslab-8529a7dbcd84ad17.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libfutures_task-6792b072bbadce72.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libpin_utils-1ab839ae12359ac8.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libzstd-d09000b18c72c2c4.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libzstd_safe-3310738d733e7d14.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libzstd_sys-b3c700a7b184a62c.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libflate2-4803dc8f5afd5995.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libminiz_oxide-0bdd646a06ae06a1.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libadler-b8fbacac7dd505c1.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libcrc32fast-16d8949a3123f157.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_service-9f69df04a6f79cdf.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_codec-0ea9fca4db0c2994.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libtracing-16ed2db589465660.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libtracing_core-691e967e34f92b7a.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libonce_cell-15380812d5ce38c8.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libmemchr-a1edceb083a3af9d.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libtokio_util-49831d31bcaefc77.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libfutures_sink-0959a6b228684bb9.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_rt-1bee1cd69381a707.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libtokio-e5e22a1035462873.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libsignal_hook_registry-e71b2c1eb9d87f61.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libsocket2-7b2dc8f144dba18a.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libmio-104670583e4b8eb7.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/liblog-bcfe7616ae39e41a.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libparking_lot-5664fbd51694169f.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libparking_lot_core-a978603a7424c7a5.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/liblibc-689ee379218a526f.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libcfg_if-abf2e970adcc1dfe.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libsmallvec-ba03379c181d17f4.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/liblock_api-34d350eca215620d.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libscopeguard-37a99f056ce55918.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libfutures_core-bb06b46d1fb1e7fc.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libhttp-7edcc611d1ab2511.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libitoa-05690e2a6d046937.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libbytes-0e54cc55b54259f2.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libfnv-6dbce919396546e8.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_utils-6e7065525c03c029.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libpin_project_lite-0ccfb586b15a27d7.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/liblocal_waker-7160e72c1a857bf9.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libour_story_rust-f23819310d80785e.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libdotenvy-d763a2bf9018121c.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libdiesel-8d15ee1ae8a287a0.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libbitflags-ec94e63e851da9df.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libbyteorder-a0f15e9a6fe1b446.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libmysqlclient_sys-214fd0f55c0724bf.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libchrono-a21ee0fbffa1e1c7.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libnum_traits-697e890d75bdf786.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libiana_time_zone-c7988b21e97d737a.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libcore_foundation_sys-89cad00fc508a534.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libserde-73a26f91cba0ebfc.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/liburl-84072ef94ae4cc11.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libidna-813cfca6a105557e.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libunicode_normalization-d91e6285d8fca3d6.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libtinyvec-da73a9eafa9ce3f8.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libtinyvec_macros-2e9fccffa5fbcd1d.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libunicode_bidi-e2941234f5418a06.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libform_urlencoded-e23c76fadf036986.rlib" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libpercent_encoding-5347f913cf8391d0.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-7f95fd207255b41e.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libpanic_unwind-97393370543e3207.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libobject-a3d7c43b176960f9.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libmemchr-6371ee3a4bb27ae4.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libaddr2line-a7cf1a11761951bf.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libgimli-dad018a8d4ef8593.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_demangle-913776ff724458d1.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd_detect-364b04ba0ead75b3.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libhashbrown-918cdfbdd32cf1d1.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-424311e8ba1b9112.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libminiz_oxide-d4352744eff98311.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libadler-dd9df5b2170395b8.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libunwind-6b98b9caf95b8907.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libcfg_if-d4913584d9013c52.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/liblibc-04f062133e43a7ac.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc-5397ff6f88f2713a.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-5142793ba4eb4c05.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-24a1e099f55e6f0d.rlib" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/libcompiler_builtins-9ca5cbf9e98b80b9.rlib" "-liconv" "-lmysqlclient" "-lz" "-lzstd" "-lssl" "-lcrypto" "-lresolv" "-framework" "CoreFoundation" "-lSystem" "-lc" "-lm" "-L" "/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib" "-o" "/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/our_story_rust-0cda4beb343ae7f3" "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: ld: library 'ssl' not found
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
          

error: could not compile `rust` (bin "rust") due to 1 previous error

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/jun/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/rustc --crate-name our_story_rust --edition=2021 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=214 --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C split-debuginfo=unpacked -C metadata=0cda4beb343ae7f3 -C extra-filename=-0cda4beb343ae7f3 --out-dir /Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps --extern actix_cors=/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_cors-4c3933e1e73abde7.rlib --extern actix_web=/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libactix_web-07079197f6761201.rlib --extern chrono=/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libchrono-a21ee0fbffa1e1c7.rlib --extern diesel=/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libdiesel-8d15ee1ae8a287a0.rlib --extern dotenvy=/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libdotenvy-d763a2bf9018121c.rlib --extern our_story_rust=/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libour_story_rust-f23819310d80785e.rlib --extern serde=/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/deps/libserde-73a26f91cba0ebfc.rlib -L native=/Users/jun/Desktop/project/rust/target/debug/build/zstd-sys-9d57269d9a809450/out -L native=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/lib` (exit status: 1)




I found a solution. In my case not connected cargo - homebrew
So was not found openssl.
export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:$(brew --prefix)/lib"
This command is connect cargo - homebrew.

This error likely means that you need openssl installed and/or properly linked.

Yes, I think so too. So I tried install openssl but same.
And it was already installed

Can you find and provide us how exactly the failing cc command looks like? It should be somewhere in the build logs. Or at least which crate exactly fails.

Did you want this log? I have attached all logs.

You can enable the "vendored" feature on the openssl crate. Then it should built its own ssl library.

"So I tried install openssl but same" - did you install libssl or libssl-dev? You can find the correct command for your distribution here.

I tried run "cargo add openssl". Then it is work!! Thank you @Finomnis
But I have one question. Why doesn't it work automatically?

If need other library, Why doesn't download automatically?

Because openssl is dynamically linked. Prefer rust-tls instead if the library you use support it, which is statically linked.

@bli00 OpenSSL is dynamically linked by default, but the "vendored" feature makes it statically linked with its own ssl build

@iubns You mean cargo add openssl --features vendored? cargo add openssl shouldn't change anything.
